# How do you prevent the back button from closing an application from the main activity?

Tags: java, android-fragments, android-activity, activity-finish, onbackpressed

I am having a problem with my activity closing when i am trying to display a fragment.  I am trying to have my application ask the user to rate my application when they press the back button to exit my application from the main screen.  This is supposed to display a fragment asking to rate it now or later.  The fragment appears for about 1 second then the application closes before the user can make a choice.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Sorry.  I could not get that first Override statement to post properly.  That goes in your main activity.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but could you please 1) clean up your code formatting, and 2) make the "question" part of this post an actual question and then supply a separate answer?

Comment: @medic_ma IMO, Questions are supposed to be in the question part and answers in the answers part. If I were you, I would post a question with what I was facing and I would answer the same question with the solution that I came up with. This is how this site works.

Comment: And thank you Mage for the edits   :*

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with:

I am going to show you what I did to implement the fragment and how I prevented it from closing the activity bypassing the fragment.

In my main activity I added:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     final DialogFragment rate = new RateMe();
   rate.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Rate");
}
```

**Be sure to remove the super statement from the Override to stop the button push from CLOSING OUT YOUR APPLICATION completely when the back button is pushed.**

I created a blank fragment activity with an xml called "RateMe".  I left the xml blank after removing the "Hllo World" but be sure to double check your tools:context=   .  This was a mistake I made and it did not match my package.  Simple fix.  Just change it to your package name.

Then in the fragment i put:

```
public class RateMe extends DialogFragment {

public static RateMe newInstance(int title) {
    RateMe frag = new RateMe();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
   // args.putInt("title", title);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setTitle("Rate Me");
    builder.setMessage(R.string.Rate);
```

//Create a string in your res values strings.xml file.  This will be your //R.string that appears on your fragment^^^^  Then continue by adding......

```
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes, I Will", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            Uri uri = Uri.pa(RateMe.this);rse("market://details?id=****PUT YOUR GOOGLE PLAY URL INFO HERE");
            Intent myAppLinkToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            myAppLinkToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
            try {
                startActivity(myAppLinkToMarket);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), " unable to find market app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Not Now", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            System.exit(0);    //this will close the application
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

}

This worked perfectly for me.  Hope this can help someone.